# Dedicated server: will switching from a HDDs to a SSDs reduce I/O usage?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, centos, nginx, mp4

I have a kind of video (mp4) hosting site. The last 2 years there were no problems with the site. But now I have encountered a problem with I/O usage: [iotop command results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRbPM.jpg)

I am currently using a 10x8TB HDDs (80TB in total). I plan to upgrade/migrate to a 12 TB SSD. Will this improve (reduce) I/O usage?

Comment: Have you analyzed which videos are requested how frequently? Most probable the distribution will follow the power law. If this turns out to be true it could be sufficient to move only the most viewed videos to SSD storage, or even to a virtual RAM disk.

Comment: Do you have a real performance problem or just don't like the iotop picture? Did the load increase? Do you use a hardware RAID controller?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SSDs will help I/O times but not technically I/O usage - your users still need to access the same amount of data. Storage I/O is by far the biggest bottleneck for most applications.

There are other things that will help as well:

- Nginx tuning
- Nginx cache and/or proxy for it and/or underlying protocols like PHP
- RAID use - even RAID1 will improve read times
- Hardware - nvme/m.2 SSDs will offer better performance than SATA

Answer (score -1):

Yes is the short answer.  Long answer - it depends on where you are viewing the I/O from. if your typical user is WAN based then the answer is "maybe".  If they are on an Ethernet LAN - probably yes".  If they are on a wifi LAN then the answer is "maybe". Communication (I/O data is 2-way communication is a long chain of links.  But how beneficial will this to you or the user; given the cost of this move.